# Subsonic 3 State

Tags: subsonic, subsonic3

could you please describe in just few words state of the Subsonic 3 project? Will you share the sources, when we can expect the release. How are things with development, what problems have you meet and so on...

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

Currently I'm hammering away on refinements as I use S3 to build out a project I'm working on. I'm trying to get it to a respectable, solid point so you don't have to keep telling me about silly bugs.

For instance - I found and eliminated a dumb join bug the other day that's been absolutely plaguing me :).

I need to make sure the working experience is what I imagine it to be: as close to 0 friction as possible. I'm also trying to work up our documentation so you don't have to guess on things - you can see this here:

http://subsonicproject.com/docs

I have some great people helping me, but I've frozen commits to the core stuff outside of myself for now so we don't get any regressions.

I know people want to use it - I need to tune it and so people will have to wait a bit.